# Swift 4 SKSpriteNode cast to CustomClass

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Hello so what I'm trying to do is create a spriteNode programmatically and assign it a class. So that I can easily manage the nodes characteristics, such as custom level, guns, hp, etc...
heres how I'm trying to do that.

```
let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "charcter") as? Dummyplayer
    player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    player.size.height = 75
    player.size.width = 75
    addChild(player)
    player.position.x = CGFloat(x)
    player.position.y = CGFloat(y)
```

but it fails saying it cannot cast type SKSpriteNode to type game.Dummplayer,, the class Dummyplayer is of type SKSpriteNode so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a `SKSpriteNode` and then you are casting it to `DummyPlayer`. The cast will always fail because player is **NOT** a `DummyPlayer`.

### Solution

Given the Dummyplayer class defined as follow

```
class Dummyplayer: SKSpriteNode { }
```

You need to create a value of type `Dummyplayer`

```
if let player = Dummyplayer(imageNamed: "character") {
    ....
}
```

Comment: This gives me an error, says Incorrect argument label, ImageNamed, expected ‘coder:’,,, My dummyplayer class is setup just like that as well

Comment: @DanielCisneros You probably defined your own `init` in `Dummyplayer`, right?